# How do you download Calibre on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, 32-bit, drm, calibre

It sounds simple, but I'm not a coder and I have a few hoops to jump through:

1. How do you download a 32-bit version, and
2. Is there a DRM removal plugin that works with it?

I've agonized over this for weeks and I'm throwing in the towel. I need help.

EDIT: I tried sudo apt-get --install-suggests --fix-missing install calibre and that worked better, but now it says "E: Failed to fetch [http://ports.ubuntu.com/"](http://ports.ubuntu.com/%22) etc. Now what does that mean?

Comment: "Linux" is vague. Exactly which release of Ubuntu do you want to install Calibre upon?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 I think. I downloaded UserLAnd last month.

Comment: Calibre is in the Ubuntu repositories, so it's a simple `sudo apt install calibre`. Calibre is also available as a Snap: `sudo snap install calibre`. Both work very well. While the Calibre developers would *prefer* that you manually install their upstream repository, it's YOUR system. You get to decide.

Comment: I'm confused: Ubuntu 20.04 is 64-bit only.

Answer (score 0):

There are [instructions on the calibre Web site](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux) for downloading and installing. They say it runs on 32-bit systems. Note that calibre requires Python 3.8 or newer.

The command is:

```bash
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh | sudo sh /dev/stdin
```

Regarding DRM removal, as I'm not sure that linking to those is OK on this site, I'll suggest you run a Web search for "DeDRM".

Comment: Or perhaps 'noDRM-DeDRM_tools'; I believe Apprentice Harper has taken a break...